# Popup on click with D3 Force Layout

Tags: jquery, d3.js, popup

I'm building a network based on the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simonraper/jz2AU/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=jz2AU) and my question is the following:

I would like to integrate a popup window that shows extra information about a certain node. This window has to be able to contain an image and a link.

I already looked for a solution myself, but since this is my first time with D3, I can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks in advance for any of your replies!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js?2.9.3"></script>
<style>

.node {
stroke: #000;
stroke-opacity: .6;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.link {
stroke: #999;
stroke-opacity: .6;
}

h3 {
color: #ffffff;
text-align:center;  
font-style: italic;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: "Helvetica";
}

.node text {
stroke: #fff !important;
color: #ffffff !important;
font-family: helvetica;
font-size: 15px;
fill: #ffffff;
stroke-width:0px !important;
}

.d3-tip {
line-height: 1;
color: #ff00ff;
}
</style>
<header>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-              tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"> </script>
</header>
<body>
<script type="application/json" id="mis">
{
    "nodes": [{
        "name": "Go.To.Market",
            "group": 1
    }, {
        "name": "Data.Science",
            "group": 1
    }, {
        "name": "Digital.Excellence",
            "group": 1
    }, {
        "name": "Customer.Innovation",
            "group": 1
    }, {
        "name": "XYZ",
            "group": 1
    }, {
        "name": "Digital",
            "group": 1
    }, {
        "name": "RES",
            "group": 2
    }, {
        "name": "CV",
            "group": 2
    }, {
        "name": "ECP",
            "group": 2
    }, {
        "name": "MET",
            "group": 2
    }, {
        "name": "ONC",
            "group": 2
    }, {
        "name": "TAs",
            "group": 2
    }, {
        "name": "IMM",
            "group": 2
    }, {
        "name": "CNS",
            "group": 2
    }, {
        "name": "BIO.SIM",
            "group": 2
    }, {
        "name": "HealthCare.R&D.Medicine.MAPOR",
            "group": 3
    }, {
        "name": "MAPOR",
            "group": 3
    }, {
        "name": "CVG",
            "group": 3
    }, {
        "name": "TMCP",
            "group": 3
    }, {
        "name": "X.RAY",
            "group": 3
    }, {
        "name": "DRA",
            "group": 3
    }, {
        "name": "MED",
            "group": 3
    }, {
        "name": "Legal&Patents",
            "group": 3
    }, {
        "name": "GMIF",
            "group": 3
    }, {
        "name": "OPU",
            "group": 3
    }, {
        "name": "Region",
            "group": 3
    }, {
        "name": "RBBI",
            "group": 3
    }, {
        "name": "BIG",
            "group": 3
    }, {
        "name": "BMHCI",
            "group": 3
    }],
        "links": [{
        "source": 0,
            "target": 5,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 1,
            "target": 5,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 2,
            "target": 5,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 3,
            "target": 5,
            "value": 1
    }, {
        "source": 4,
            "target": 5,
            "value": 1
    }
    , {
        "source": 6,
            "target": 11,
            "value": 2
    }
    , {
        "source": 7,
            "target": 11,
            "value": 2
    }
    , {
        "source": 9,
            "target": 11,
            "value": 2
    }
    , {
        "source": 10,
            "target": 11,
            "value": 2
    }
    , {
        "source": 7,
            "target": 8,
            "value": 2
    }
    , {
        "source": 9,
            "target": 8,
            "value": 2
    }, {
        "source": 12,
            "target": 11,
            "value": 2
    }, {
        "source": 13,
            "target": 11,
            "value": 2
    }, {
        "source": 14,
            "target": 11,
            "value": 2
    }, {
        "source": 16,
            "target": 15,
            "value": 3
    }, {
        "source": 17,
            "target": 15,
            "value": 3
    }
    , {
        "source": 18,
            "target": 15,
            "value": 3
    }, {
        "source": 18,
            "target": 19,
            "value": 3
    }
    , {
        "source": 21,
            "target": 15,
            "value": 3
    }, {
        "source": 21,
            "target": 20,
            "value": 3
    }, {
        "source": 22,
            "target": 15,
            "value": 3
    },
    {
        "source": 23,
            "target": 15,
            "value": 3
    }
    ,
    {
        "source": 23,
            "target": 24,
            "value": 3
    }
    ,
    {
        "source": 23,
            "target": 25,
            "value": 3
    },
    {
        "source": 26,
            "target": 15,
            "value": 3
    }
    ,
    {
        "source": 28,
            "target": 15,
            "value": 3
    },
    {
        "source": 27,
            "target": 15,
            "value": 3
    },
    {
        "source": 5,
            "target": 11,
            "value": 3
    },
    {
        "source": 11,
            "target": 15,
            "value": 3
    },
    {
        "source": 15,
            "target": 5,
            "value": 3
    }

    ]
}
</script>
<script>
//Constants for the SVG
var width = 1500,
height = 1500;
//Set up the colour scale
var color = d3.scale.category20();
//Set up the force layout
var force = d3.layout.force()
.charge(-2000)
.linkDistance(100)
.size([width, height]);

//Append a SVG to the body of the html page. Assign this SVG as an object to svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);


//Set up tooltip
var tip = d3.tip()
.attr('class', 'd3-tip')
.offset([-10, 0])
.html(function (d) {
return  d.name + "";
})
svg.call(tip);
//Read the data from the mis element 
var mis = document.getElementById('mis').innerHTML;
graph = JSON.parse(mis);

//Creates the graph data structure out of the json data
force.nodes(graph.nodes)
.links(graph.links)
.start();

//Create all the line svgs but without locations yet
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
.data(graph.links)
.enter().append("line")
.attr("class", "link")
.style("stroke-width", function (d) {
return Math.sqrt(d.value);
});

//Do the same with the circles for the nodes - no 
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
.data(graph.nodes)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "node")
.call(force.drag);
node.append("circle")
.attr("r", 30)
.style("fill", function (d) {
return color(d.group);
})
.call(force.drag)
.on('dblclick', connectedNodes)
.on('mouseover', tip.show) //Added
.on('mouseout', tip.hide); //Added 


node.append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("dy", 5)
  .text(function(d) { return d.name })
  .style("stroke", "gray");
//Added code

//Now we are giving the SVGs co-ordinates - the force layout is generating the co-ordinates which this code is using to update the attributes of the SVG elements
force.on("tick", function () {
link.attr("x1", function (d) {
    return d.source.x;
})
    .attr("y1", function (d) {
    return d.source.y;
})
    .attr("x2", function (d) {
    return d.target.x;
})
    .attr("y2", function (d) {
    return d.target.y;
});
d3.selectAll("circle").attr("cx", function (d) {
    return d.x;
})
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
    return d.y;
});
d3.selectAll("text").attr("x", function (d) {
    return d.x;
})
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return d.y;
});
});

//---Insert-------

//Toggle stores whether the highlighting is on
var toggle = 0;

//Create an array logging what is connected to what
var linkedByIndex = {};
for (i = 0; i < graph.nodes.length; i++) {
linkedByIndex[i + "," + i] = 1;
};
graph.links.forEach(function (d) {
linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
});

//This function looks up whether a pair are neighbours  
function neighboring(a, b) {
return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index];
}

function connectedNodes() {

if (toggle == 0) {
    //Reduce the opacity of all but the neighbouring nodes
    d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;
    node.style("opacity", function (o) {
        return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.1;
    });

    link.style("opacity", function (o) {
        return d.index==o.source.index | d.index==o.target.index ? 1 : 0.1;
    });

    //Reduce the op

    toggle = 1;
} else {
    //Put them back to opacity=1
    node.style("opacity", 1);
    link.style("opacity", 1);
    toggle = 0;
}

}

//---End Insert---
</script>   
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is still an issue but you're using a a D3 tooltip. If you add the following to your CSS header, you should be fine.

`<script type='text/javascript' src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"> </script>`

I hope this helped.